# Vuejs back and forth transition skipping ahead to last frame on back

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm creating a slider element of 2 items only. I want them to smoothly slide back and forth to the left and right when I click back / next. It works well when I click next, elements scroll and fade, but when I click back, the first element jumps ahead in time no matter what I do, this gif explains a bit more visually:

[image]

Edit: Here is a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/273583/

This is my css:

```
.first-slide-enter{
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translatex(-100%);
  transition: all 1.5s ease-out;
}
.first-slide-enter-to{
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translatex(0);
  transition: all 1.5s ease-out;
}
.first-slide-leave-to{
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translatex(-100%);
    transition: all 1.5s ease-out;
}


.second-slide-enter{
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translatex(0);
  transition: all 1.5s ease-out;
}
.second-slide-enter-to{
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translatex(-100%);
    transition: all 1.5s ease-out;
}
.second-slide-leave-to{
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translatex(0);
    transition: all 1.5s ease-out;
}
```

This is my html:

```
        <transition name="first-slide">
            <div v-if="!newShortcut.link">

                <div id="drop-shortcut" class="drag-file clickable" @click="addShortcut">
                    <i class="fas fa-file-upload fa-lg"></i>
                    <p style="margin:20px 0 0;">Drag file here
                        <br> or click to browse</p>
                </div>                      
                <div>
                        <button @click="newShortcut.link = !newShortcut.link">Next</button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </transition>

        <transition name="second-slide">
            <div v-if="newShortcut.link">
                <div id="drop-icon" class="drag-file" @click="">
                    <i class="far fa-file-image fa-lg"></i>
                    <p style="margin:20px 0 0;">Drag file here
                        <br> or click to browse</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button @click="newShortcut.link = !newShortcut.link">back</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </transition>
```

How to make this work?

Comment: I'm looking at it but if you could post a working fiddle that'd help a lot

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/273583/

Comment: @raphadko small tip: use a `will-change` css property, to boost fps of your animation (seems like a bit laggy for me). https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/will-change (supported only by modern browsers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So @Julian is correct for the blocking issue, but there is another way to fix it that might work for you better. See this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/xcmn76Lo/

Basically what was needed was some tweaking to the second slide. There is a hook you can use similar to `enter` to specify where it starts leaving from. In this case since the other div reserves its space immediately, you need to start the leave transition offsetting appropriately.

```
.second-slide-leave{
  transform:translatex(-100%);
}
```

Then instead of transition to 100%, set `leave-to` to 0 (aka where it WOULD end up if moved over by the incoming div).

```
.second-slide-leave-to{
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translatex(0);
    transition: all 1.5s ease-out;
}
```

Comment: Wow, it works! I tried this before, but I put the "transition: all 1.5s ease-out;" property inside .second-slide-leave too, which then breaks it. Any ideas why?

Comment: It's because it is essentially fighting to get *back* to the position it started at in the same amount of time that it would use to animate itself out. You can kind of see the effect happen if you set it to `transition: all .2s ease-out;` on `.second-slide-leave`. It "jerks" itself back a bit. But if you put no transition on it, it immediately snaps itself to the offset position which is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was because of how your elements are displayed. Each slide is a `block`, so it occupies a space in your layout.

So when you were at the second slide and click the back button.
What happens before that is, there was no slide 1 in the layout and when vue starts to insert the slide 1 back, it occupies a space which causes the second slide to suddenly jump from left to right.

So to fix that behavior, you can make each slide's position as `absolute` so that if they are inserted back, they will not cause such behavior because `absolute` position will not affect it's neighboring element's position unlike the `relative` position.

```css
#app>div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

and update the css transition for the second slide a little bit:

```css
.second-slide-enter {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translatex(100%);
  transition: all 1.5s ease-out;
}

.second-slide-enter-to {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translatex(0);
  transition: all 1.5s ease-out;
}

.second-slide-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translatex(100%);
  transition: all 1.5s ease-out;
}
```

Here's the full JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/273631/

Comment: Seems to work, but since the parent is fixed, on my website it takes 0 height because all children are absolute positioned. Any ideas on how to do this without using absolute?

Comment: By the way, even when it's not absolute, it should start leave with transformx(-100%), so even though the other element is taking its place it would still be there, right?

Comment: No, the `translateX` doesn't actually move your element "literally". What I mean by that is, the space that was occupied by the box is still on the same space even though it looks like it was in the far left. You can only achieve `true` changes to position by using `left` and not 'transform: translateX'.  And when you also use `left`, `top`, `right` or `bottom`, you would need to set the `position` property of the element to either `relative`, `fixed`, `absolute`, etc... to make it work.

Comment: Your best choice is to use `position`, but you would need to specifically set the height of the container.

Comment: @JulianPaoloDayag see my answer, you should just be able to offset the start of the animation and it should work fine.